# Asus G53SX How to use the recovery partition

Tags: laptop, system-restore, factory-defaults

I am trying to use the recovery partition on my Asus G53SX laptop, but the instructions in the included booklet don't match up with what happens on the computer.

It says press <kbd>F9</kbd> during bootup and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to select windows setup. Then select the language you want to recover, and so on.

When I press <kbd>F9</kbd> I end up in the boot manager and from there I can access safe mode and all these things. The closest thing I can find in this list is "Repair your computer" but this menu takes me to recovery points and backup images, none which are mentioned in the booklet.

How can I use the recovery partition to restore my laptop to factory state?

Comment: Have you at any stage played with (i.e. changed) the partitions on your laptop?

Comment: No, all the partitions are in the exact same way as when I got the laptop

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but try hitting Esc or F10 on boot.

Comment: ESC opens up a window allowing me to choose to boot from P0 or P2 or enter setup. Both P0 and P2 starts win7 normally

Comment: F10 sends me to a sub menu of boot options. A page with a path to winload.exe

Answer (score 0):

You're already there. If you go into "repair your computer" there should be either an option under one of the backup/restore sections, or you might have to go through one of the wizards to get to an "advanced options" screen.

Comment: The "Repair your computer" option that @Amento is getting is the standard Windows (Vista or 7) boot option, which is part of a Windows install or on the install CD. What he is looking for is the manufacturers recovery utility (i.e. that reads their OEM image off of a hidden partition and restores the laptop to the condition it was when it left the store - including bloat ware, drivers, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I apologise for not explaining that in a better way. Thank you, Windos.

Comment: Yes it's the default windows recovery...but within that is where the manufacturer puts their "restore to factory defaults" option. I can think of 2 different places it might be:

1. Inside one of the "restore to backup" sections. If you go into the menu there might be a "factory defaults" option.

2. After you click on "repair your computer", the bottom option on the list is usually the OEM's factory setting.